# Colorbox и Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, битрикс

Добрый день. В cms Битрикс у меня по нажатия кнопки открывается форма в колорбоксе, но далее при ее заполнении и отправке - ничего не происходит, ajax не отрабатывает, хотя если открыть ее не в колорбоксе, а просто на странице - все работает отлично. Как это решить?

Comment: А Код покажите?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проблема решилось сменой колорбокс на фэнсибокс, другого способа не нашел